# How to remove item in angularjs using foreach in a Asp.net MVC Model

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to angularjs, and i want to know how to remove an item from a model inside a model using foreach? I am using asp.net MVC and angularjs

for example in my first model entity,

```
public class WeekData    
{    
    public virtual ICollection<Name> Names{ get; set; }  
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="week in model.WeekData">
     <tr ng-repeat="name in week.Names">
         <td><a type="button" ng-click="removeName(name.Id)"></td>
     </tr>
</div>
```

in AngularJs

```
$scope.removeName = function (index) {
    index.preventDefault();
    _.each($scope.model.WeekData, function (week) {
        _.each(week.Names, function (name, index) { 
            name.splice(index, 1)
        });
    });
};
```

I hope someone can answer, I'm used to splice but i don't have an idea how to use it in a foreach.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are combining Server side models into angular js which is not the way angular works.

Firstly, you will have to fetch WeekData object from server.

On server side, create a controller action as -

```
public string GetWeekData(){


     JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
     return js.SerializeObject(model.WeekData);
}
```

On client side, you can make use of HttpClient module.

Have Http injected as below in your controller -

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
```

Define a  function to get WeekData object from server ->

```
$scope.GetWeekDataObj = function()
{
    $http.get('<Path to API>').then(function(result){
    $scope.WeekData = result;
});

}
```

Function to remove object

```
$scope.Remove= function(name){
for(var i = 0; i <  $scope.WeekData.Names.length; i++ ){

if($scope.WeekData.Names[i] == name)  // compare as per the primary key
   $scope.WeekData.Names.splice(i,1);
}
}
```

Once WeekdData object is avaliable, you can then iterate over

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="name in WeekData.Names">
<td>
<button ng-click="Remove(name)">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. i'll try this one out. will update. thanks!